# using arrow function for binding in react

Tags: reactjs

new there.
I started learning React and I have a code problem - I can't figure it out.
I tried to find the problem here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

I perform a bind - and send the function to another component.

```
{this.state.array.map((char, index) => <CharComponent style={mystyle} character={char} click={(index) => this.deleteHandler(index)} key={index}></CharComponent>)}
```

```
deleteHandler = (index) => {
    let copyArray = [...this.state.array];
    console.log('copyArray: ' + copyArray);
    copyArray.splice(index, 1);
    console.log('copyArray: ' + copyArray);
    this.setState({ length: copyArray.length, string: copyArray.join(''), array: copyArray });
  }
```

I can not get the index - it shows me that it is an object and not a number.

I did a bind - I sent the index as a parameter - and then called it in the function

Why should the brackets be empty?
click={(index) => this.deleteHandler(index)

Comment: arrow functions cannot be bind. Use "normal" function if you want to bind it

Comment: Delete the index in parentheses, in click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the index from the parameters of `click()`, because when you perform a click it gives us an event object and you are actually passing the event object instead of index. That's why is not getting actual index value from map function.

See the following code for example:

```
{this.state.array.map((char, index) => <CharComponent style={mystyle} character={char} click={() => this.deleteHandler(index)} key={index}></CharComponent>)}
```

And for your question, `Why should the brackets be empty?`  As mentioned above when we perform a click gives us a javascript `Event` object in return.